# Is it faster to count data client side or server side?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ruby-on-rails

Say I have a html table of Cars with 1000 rows and I want to display the total number of cars that are a certain brand in a sidebar. Is it faster to use JavaScript and loop through the table rows, find number of cars the equal brand *X*, and then append that total in the sidebar or is it faster to just create a scope in my model like `scope -> { where(brand = 'toyota' }.count`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Databases are optimized for these kind of things. So your best move is to go with queries when possible. Plus is less error prone.